# Remove page content except for table using .replace()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, replace

I've been trying to extract a table from the page (queue.htm) that i loaded through .ajax(). I wanted to use .replace(regex) to remove everything else aside from the table i need but i don't know exactly how to do it.

```
 $j.ajax({
          url: 'queue.htm',
          cache: false,
        success:handler= function(data) {
              //use .replace here to extract table from data
              //split extracted table into array
        }
      })
```

I tried using .load("queue.htm #tableId) before to get only the table from the page. It works but it's not giving me the result i want as i intended to split that table to an array.

Is there a way i can just extract the table from the page and at the same time, i will be able to manipulate the extracted table in the js? Thank you very much!

Comment: You don't want a regex, you want to get the table and manipulate it with DOM methods, but you're not telling us what you want to do here ?

Comment: Hi @adeneo ,thanks for pointing it out. Yes, that's actually want i want to do... to get the table via .ajax() url and split it into array. I figured that i don't really need a regex to do it. I used `$j(data).find('#tableId').html()` instead to extract the table from the page. All that's left for me to learn is how to split it to array using the split() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str = '<html><table><table>test</table></table></html>"';
str = str.match(/(<table>.*<\/table>)/g);
console.log( str );
```

Comment: Thank you. Your provided sample worked just fine but when i replaced the str with data returned from the ajax call, it returns null instead.

Comment: Assuming the data return from your ajax is a JSON object, u will need to convert the object to string JSON.stringify()